# How to set Position: relative parent's height according to it's Position: absolute children?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The html code inside dvReporte and the "style####" classes comes from a custom reports API and it is always different depending on the report, therefore I can't customize it to use "float" instead of "position: absolute".

The report used to overflow up and down, but by making dvReporte "position: relative;" i got the content to stay inside the parent div.

The problem is that dvReporte's height is 0, and according to my previous research you can't set it right with css when you use "position: absolute". Is there a way to get the total height of the parent div based on the height of all it's children?

HTML example:

```
<div id="dvReporte" style="position: relative;">
            <div class="style0000" style="position: absolute; left: 268px; top: 24px; width: 281px; height: 19px; z-index: 0;">Artículos&nbsp;Deportivos&nbsp;2000,&nbsp;S.A.&nbsp;de&nbsp;C.V.</div>
            <div style="position: absolute; left: 24px; top: 72px; width: 768px; height: 15px; z-index: 1;">
                <img src="Buffer_htm_images/T35020_Z100_0001.gif?rand=562" width="768" height="15" border="0" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="style0001" style="position: absolute; left: 366px; top: 82px; width: 292px; height: 13px; z-index: 2; overflow: hidden;">
                <div style="position: absolute; left: 102px; top: 0px; width: 190px;">Al&nbsp;31/Dic./2020</div>
            </div>
            <div class="style0002" style="position: absolute; left: 324px; top: 47px; width: 169px; height: 26px; z-index: 3;">Balance&nbsp;General</div>
            <div class="style0003" style="position: absolute; left: 106px; top: 100px; width: 600px; height: 13px; z-index: 4; overflow: hidden;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;A&nbsp;C&nbsp;T&nbsp;I&nbsp;V&nbsp;O</div>
            <div class="style0004" style="position: absolute; left: 106px; top: 130px; width: 260px; height: 13px; z-index: 5; overflow: hidden;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="style0001" style="position: absolute; left: 106px; top: 145px; width: 600px; height: 13px; z-index: 6; overflow: hidden;">Circulante</div>
            <div class="style0004" style="position: absolute; left: 106px; top: 160px; width: 260px; height: 13px; z-index: 7; overflow: hidden;">CAJA</div>
            <div class="style0004" style="position: absolute; left: 366px; top: 160px; width: 98px; height: 13px; z-index: 8; overflow: hidden;">
                <div style="position: absolute; left: 54px; top: 0px; width: 44px;">1,001.00</div>
            </div>
            <div class="style0004" style="position: absolute; left: 106px; top: 175px; width: 260px; height: 13px; z-index: 9; overflow: hidden;">BANCOS1</div>
            <div class="style0004" style="position: absolute; left: 366px; top: 175px; width: 98px; height: 13px; z-index: 10; overflow: hidden;">
                <div style="position: absolute; left: 42px; top: 0px; width: 56px;">154,190.03</div>
            </div>
            <div class="style0004" style="position: absolute; left: 106px; top: 190px; width: 260px; height: 13px; z-index: 11; overflow: hidden;">Bancos2</div>
            <div class="style0004" style="position: absolute; left: 366px; top: 190px; width: 98px; height: 13px; z-index: 12; overflow: hidden;">
                <div style="position: absolute; left: 48px; top: 0px; width: 50px;">22,829.97</div>
            </div>
            <div class="style0001" style="position: absolute; left: 106px; top: 205px; width: 260px; height: 13px; z-index: 13; overflow: hidden;">Totales&nbsp;de&nbsp;Bancos</div>
            <div class="style0001" style="position: absolute; left: 366px; top: 205px; width: 98px; height: 13px; z-index: 14; overflow: hidden;">
                <div style="position: absolute; left: 36px; top: 0px; width: 62px;">178,021.00</div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

CSS example:

```
.style0000 {font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 12pt; white-space: nowrap;}
.style0001 {font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 8pt; font-weight: bold; white-space: nowrap;}
.style0002 {font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 16pt; font-weight: bold; white-space: nowrap;}
.style0003 {font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 8pt; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; white-space: nowrap;}
.style0004 {font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 8pt; white-space: nowrap;}
.style0005 {font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 7pt; white-space: nowrap;}
```

Thanks for your time.

Report example, with its height set manually:

[image: Report example, with its height set manually]

Comment: By using `position: absolute` on the child elements, they are taken out of the positioning flow and the parent element will no longer take any notice of those elements. If you can show an image of what you are trying to achieve, it is possible that a different solution could be proposed.

Comment: I just want to set the div's height so it displays like the image, the default height is 0.

Comment: You should use a table to layout this data. It's what tables are intended for. Furthermore, CSS has a number of layout options including document flow, grids, flex-box, floats, etc. These should all be preferred over absolute positioning. Once you use absolute positioning you have to make all further decisions about layout.

Comment: I know that using  "position: absolute" it's not the best approach, but as I said, I' not programming the reports code. There is a system where you design your own reports to obtain information from your database, and those reports can be exported to pdf, html, xlsx, etc. So each user can create their own custom reports, and I get them from an API.

Comment: I've added a potential javascript solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to to do what you are asking when using CSS and absolute positioning in this manner.

You could try using javascript to set the height of the containing element:

```
// Gets containing div
const parent = document.querySelector('#dvReporte')
// Gets all children of containing div
const children = parent.children

// Stores the largest extent found (offsetTop + offsetHeight)
let largestExtent = 0

// iterate the children elements and store the largest extent found
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
  let extent = children[i].offsetHeight + children[i].offsetTop
  if (extent > largestExtent) largestExtent = extent
}

// Set the height of the containing element, adds an extra 20px for padding at the bottom
parent.style.height = `${largestExtent + 20}px`
```

https://codepen.io/mward-sudo/pen/abWExya?editors=1111

---

I understand the outputting tool is your problem, but for reference, the code in this report should properly be done using a table to do the majority of the layout, like below.

```css
.wrapper {
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 60em;
  margin: 1em auto
}



header {
  text-align: right;
}

table {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.total {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    <p>Artículos Deportivos 2000, S.A. de C.V.</p>
    <h1>Balance General</h1>
    <p class="date">Al 31/Dic./2020</p>
  </header>
  
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 20em; border-bottom: 1px solid black;">A C T I V O</th>
        <th style="width: 7em;"></th>
        <th style="width: 7em;"></th>
        <th style="width: 7em;"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Circulante</strong></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>CAJA</td>
        <td>1,001.00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>BANCOS1</td>
        <td>154,190.03</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bancos2</td>
        <td>22,829.97</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Totales de Bancos</strong></td>
        <td><strong>178,021.00</strong></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>etc.</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>etc.</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>etc.</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>etc.</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>etc.</strong></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><strong>-0.00</strong></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>etc.</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>etc.</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>etc.</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>etc.</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="total"><strong>1,000,000</strong></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, your javascript solution works and it helped me a lot, the only detail is that when the elements are not vertically together, it is necessary to take into account the space between them.
Thanks again, have a great day.

Comment: I've changed the code. Now, instead of adding heights together, the code looks for the largest extent of any of the child elements (offsetTop + offsetHeight) which gives a precise value for the lowest point of all the elements. It then adds 20px for padding.